# What is the CODEX intercept for wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

Tags: wp-login-form, password

I want to write a plugin hook for `wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`.

Does anyone know what the add_action() is for `wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`?

I searched the CODEX and could not discover it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login form actions are located in `wp-login.php` [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-login.php#L448) and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-login.php#L548).

```
// "login_form_{$action}"
login_form_lostpassword
login_form_postpass
login_form_logout

lostpassword_form
resetpass_form
register_form
```

There's also the general `login_init` which will fire for all actions.

To enqueue scripts on login, use `login_enqueue_scripts`. Right after that, `login_head` will allow you to add custom meta tags, etc. to the `<head>`.

The end of the page is injectable with `login_footer`.

- If you need to adjust (or add) errors, use `lostpassword_post`, which comes with an argument `\WP_Error $errors`.
- If it's about passwords, you can use `validate_password_reset` which
  has two arguments, first again the `\WP_Error $errors` and the
  current `\WP_User $user` as second (or another `\WP_Error` in case
  the user is errornous).

Comment: @tammy - there are a few more I've added above.

Comment: Thank you very much @Milo. `login_init` is exactly what I was looking for.